# Attempting to change include statement at compile time/run time for Verilog code

Tags: macros, verilog, test-bench

My apologies if I make any mistakes in writing this up as this is my first question. I have been working on testing some code in Verilog that would use tables/arrays of varying length and I am planning on simply including the one I currently need with an include statement. However, I have been trying to be able to change the macro for the include statement at runtime/compile time so that I can run the tests quickly, and hopefully eventually write up a .do file for it. Here is the simple include statement:

```
`define Table "dummy_table.v"
`include `Table
```

(I also tried this with `ifdef)

Then, I tried compiling it using this command:

```
vlog +define+Table=VerilogTables.v Adder.v
```

Unfortunately I always get this error:

```
# ** Error: ** while parsing macro expansion: 'Table' starting at Adder.v(18)
# ** at Adder.v(18): Filename to `include must be enclosed in "'s.
# ** Error: (vlog-13069) ** while parsing macro expansion: 'Table' starting at Adder.v(18)
```

Line 18 is the actual include statement.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message told you exactly what the problem is, you are missing the `""`'s around the file name. The code from the command line would get expanded as

```
`include VerilogTables.v
```

which is not the correct syntax. You need to add the quotes to `+define` switch

```
vlog +define+Table=\"VerilogTables.v\" Adder.v
```

This answer may have to be modified for different shells or make files

Comment: I realized that now, and it certainly makes me feel like a fool haha. Thank you so much for pointing that out dave! For some reason I keep on making small (easily fixed) errors. I really appreciate it!